# Read verbatim string from file

Tags: python, string, file-io

I need to read a string stored in a file *verbatim*. I've tried writing the string between single and double quotation marks but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's a `MWE` of what I mean:

```
with open('file.dat', mode="r") as f:
    for line in f:
        reader = line.split()
        # Read string.
        liter = str(reader[1])

print liter
```

The `file.dat` file consists of a single line like so:

```
ID  " Literal\t : "
```

where the first column contains an ID which helps me identify the line and the second column should contain the string as a single element.

This string *will not always look exactly the same*. It could have for example no character at the beginning (ie: `"Literal\t : "`) a space instead of a `\t` character (ie `" Literal  : "`) no spaces at the beginning or the end (ie: `"Literal\t :"`), etc..

The result I'm after is the same I would get doing simply (in the case of the example above):

```
liter = ' Literal\t : '
```

How could I do this?

Comment: A larger data sample would help.  `line.split(None, 1)` and `ast.literal_eval(liter[1])`, but it's usually better to avoid `literal_eval` unless you have exclusive control over contents.

Comment: If you are the one writing the .dat file, why not use a different column delimiter, like "|"?

Comment: Do you mean for the `\t` in your string to become a tab character, or do you mean for it to remain two characters, a backslash and a `t`? It's not really clear what you're trying to do and what you mean by "verbatim".

Comment: @Blckknght see updated answer. The result I'm after is exactly the same I'd get doing simply `liter = ' Literal\t : '`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your data is guaranteed to always look *exactly* like that, you could just use a regex:

```
import re

data = '''
ID  " Literal\t : "
'''

for line in data.split('\n'):
    if line:
        liter = re.search(r'"(.*)"', line).groups()[0]
        print(liter)
        print(repr(liter))
```

Result:

```
 Literal     : 
' Literal\t : '
```

Comment: Please see the updated question @senshin, what do you mean by "if your data is guaranteed to always look exactly like that"?

Comment: @Gabriel What I mean is that if each line of your data contains an ID, which doesn't contain double quotes, followed by your literal string, which is surrounded by double quotes, and not followed by anything else, then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `csv` module to read your file? It supports any delimiter character you want, and can support several ways of quoting of texts that include the delimiter. It looks like you need a space delimiter and quotes around strings that include spaces (which is the default quote style):

```
with open('file.dat', newlines="") as f: # if you're using Python 2, open in binary mode
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    for line in reader:
        print(line) # for the example data, line[1] will be " Literal\\t : "
```